# Contextual Typing does not flow backwards for a function accessed from a object literal?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I have the following class with a static method on it.

`export default class BProvider {
   static fetchSomething() { }
}`

`const providers: {[key: string]: any} = {
  "b": BProvider
};`

If I store `BProvider` as a value in an object literal given above then 
 I neither get the auto-suggestion in VSCode not `fetchSomething` takes me to a file where it was defined. I know that I've used `any` as return type in `providers` but replacing `any` with `BProvider` does not even work.

Am I doing anything wrong?

`(providers["b"]).fetchSomething()`

Comment: This isn't purely a contextual typing issue... it's the fact that the `BProvider` constructor is not of *type* `BProvider`, in the same way that the `Date` constructor is not itself a `Date`.  Change `any` to `typeof BProvider` and see if it works.

Comment: Your other problem is that by annotating `providers` as `{[key: string]: any}` you are telling TypeScript to forget that `providers.b` will be a particular type of thing.  Nothing would stop you from then writing `providers.b = 123;`, and so the subsequent `providers.b.fetchSomething()` is an error.

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems here, firstly you type the variable explicitly as having an index retuning type `any`, this means that all properties will be of type `any` and therefore you will not get type checking. If you object can only contain object of type `typeof BProvider` you can use that instead of any. Notice I said `typeof BPRovider` as you want the static interface of `BPRovider` not the instance members (since you try to access the static method):

```
export class BProvider {
    static fetchSomething() { }
}
const providers: { [key: string]: typeof BProvider } = {
    "b": BProvider
};

providers["b"].fetchSomething() // works
```

If you want to create an object that maps to different types you can use a function to help with the creation of providers and that enforces certain constrains on the members but will infer the actual type of the object literal:

```
export class BProvider {
    static fetchSomething() { }
    static other() {}
}

function createProviders<T extends { [key: string] : { fetchSomething(): void } }>(value: T) {
    return value;
}
const providers = createProviders({
    "b": BProvider
});


providers["b"].fetchSomething() // works
providers["b"].other() // works
providers["c"].fetchSomething() // does not work
```